# X forwarding over SSH from Mac to a Linux box

Tags: macos, ssh, x-windows

I need run Mac applications on a remote Mac machine and display it on a local Linux machine's X server (a lot of articles on the Internet seem to be detailing how would you do it the opposite way).

```
$ ssh -X mac-box
$ cd /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
$ ./Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Sat Oct  3 20:41:26 mac-box.local Xcode[15634] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
^C
```

1. My `$DISPLAY` variable appears to be empty. What should it look like so that forwarding works correctly?
2. Can I run OSX applications this way at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a Mac's Aqua was X, then you would not need to run X (XQuartz) to start other X programs on a Mac...

So: **no, I think you cannot do this.**

---

But, to help you get started, I'd first try to get true X programs forwarded to your Linux machine:

- On your Mac: install XQuartz if you've not yet done so (like XQuartz 2.3.4 from optional installs on the OS X 10.6 DVD, or download the latest from [the XQuartz project](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/)).
- On your Mac: change `X11Forwarding no` into `X11Forwarding yes` (and ensure there's no hash (`#`) in front of that line) by using `sudo vi /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, or using a `sed` command from Apple's [Enabling X11 Forwarding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1383.html). This will also ensure the `DISPLAY` variable is set automatically.
- On your Linux machine:

```
ssh -Y user@mac-box
xterm
```

(Some next steps might then include Googling for `Xephyr` (or the older `Xnest`). And if you run into keyboard issues: Google `xmodmap`, or use `xev` for debugging. Or for font issues: Google `xfs` and `xset +fp tcp/mac-box:7100`. But I doubt you can run Aqua programs this way.)

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. I can't run Xcode and iPhone simulator via SSH, even though I can run xterm. Also, I did not need to install XQuartz on stock 10.6 install.

Comment: @AlexB Did anything change in the last 10 years?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your main goal here is to view running Mac applications on a linux machine. Arjan is right, X forwarding won't work for this.

You should enable Screen Sharing in the Sharing pane in System Preferences. This will turn on a VNC server. Using a VNC client on your linux machine, you'll be able to see your Mac desktop. [This article](http://mac101.net/content/how-to/how-to-setup-remote-access-via-vnc-mac-based-remote-desktop-for-mac-pc-linux-iphone/) shows how to set it up on the mac side (steps 1-3), goes on (a bit too much) about setting up dyndns and opening ports in an Airport base station and then has a tiny bit at the bottom about setting up the client side (steps 20-21).

Comment: And there's also many programs out there that only share a single application (rather than the whole desktop). I think one can even do that using the latest Skype, cross-platform. (I am not sure if Skype also allows one to *control* the remote machine, rather than only peeking to its screen.)

Comment: I wish I could avoid using it. It seems VNC remains the only alternative at this point.

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
su -lm <usrname-to-proxy-for>
```

to enter into a shell where no X11 issues will occur. See manpages for details about the '-m' option.

Comment: *-m Leave the environment unmodified. The invoked shell is your login shell, and no directory changes are made.* — how is that related to the question?